# How to show an error on enter key press if textarea empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this chat which I am trying to make. Everything works ok so far but I want to show an error when I press enter if the textarea is empty. Can anyone tell me how I can do it? I've been trying many methods but nothing worked. Thank You.

```
$("#message").keypress(function(e) {
    var test = $("#Uname").val()
    var valmsg = $('#message').val();

    if (e.which == 13 && valmsg.trim()) {
        $("#chat").append("<div class='mesaj'>" + test+ ':' + valmsg + "  </div>");
        $('#message').val('');  
    }
});
```

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/azfwuzad/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by checking that the value of the textarea is not empty when the return key is pressed. Try this:

```
$("#message").keypress(function(e) {
    var test = $("#Uname").val()
    var valmsg = $('#message').val();

    if (e.which == 13 && valmsg.trim() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please type a message to send');
    } else if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#chat").append("<div class='mesaj'>" + test + ':' + valmsg + "</div>");
        $('#message').val('');
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/azfwuzad/3/)

The call to `preventDefault()` will stop the enter key press from adding a new line in an empty textarea.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan actually same functionality can be done by single word required  but it is not working :-( i missed to answer .. do you have any quick thought why it is not working ?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hey , in textarea i still get a new line ,but only after i send a text  .Can you tell me how can i fix it ? Thanks :)

Comment: In that case you need to put `e.preventDefault()` in both `if` conditions: https://jsfiddle.net/azfwuzad/15/